# Batch not checking if variable = 0

Tags: variables, batch-file

So, I'm making a game using batch coding, and I have a shop within the game that's only supposed to sell one of each item. Unfortunately, when I set the variable for the item to 1, then reduce it to 0, the code doesn't acknowledge that there are no more items to sell.

```
:ForestHagShop
cls
set WSwrdHag=1
set WShldHag=1
set GldApHag=1
echo "What would you like, my dear?"
echo 1.) Wooden Sword  - 50 gold - (+10 Attack)
echo 2.) Wooden Shield - 70 gold - (+30 Max HP)
echo 3.) Shiny Apple   - 40 gold - (+30 HP)
echo.
set /p input6=)
if %input6% equ 1 goto BuySwrdHagChk
if %input6% equ 2 goto BuyShldHag
if %input6% equ 3 goto BuyAplHag

:BuySwrdHagChk
echo Checking...
echo.
echo **PRESS A KEY**
Pause >nul
if WSwrdHag LSS 1 goto OutSwordHag

:BuySwrdHag
set /a Gold=Gold-50
set /a Attack=Attack+10
set /a WSwrdHag=WSwrdHag-1
echo You hand over 50 gold for the
echo wooden sword. Your new stats are...
echo Health Points .. .. .. %HP%/%MaxHP%
echo Gold .. .. .. .. .. .. %Gold%
echo Attack Power  .. .. .. %Attack%
echo.
echo **PRESS A KEY**
pause >nul
goto ForestHagShop

:OutSwordHag
echo The hag frowns, looking at you like
echo you're stupid. 
echo "You already bought my wood sword,
echo idiot!"
echo.
echo **PRESS A KEY**
pause >nul
goto ForestHagShop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the `%` delimiters when checking the variable...

Change

```
if WSwrdHag LSS 1 goto OutSwordHag
```

to be

```
if %WSwrdHag% LSS 1 goto OutSwordHag
```

and also these

```
set /a Gold=Gold-50
set /a Attack=Attack+10
set /a WSwrdHag=WSwrdHag-1
```

to be

```
set /a Gold=%Gold%-50
set /a Attack=%Attack%+10
set /a WSwrdHag=%WSwrdHag%-1
```

Comment: The sword is still in stock and loops infinitely.. D:

Comment: That's because at the end of :BuyswrdHag you loop bak to ForestHagShop where you reset WSwrdHag to 1 .....

Comment: You are correct about the `if` compare but the `set /a` commands don't need the % signs around variable names.